# What are all the single game records broken in the 5OT game between Blue Jackets vs Lightning?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

The Columbus Blue Jackets and the Tampa Bay Lightning played a marathon 5 overtime long game on their series opener of the round of 16 of the 2019-20 Stanley Cup playoffs. At a total length of 150:27 this game was the 4th longest NHL game ever!

What are all the single game records that were broken during this game?

Comment: My trouble with this sort of question is that there's no list of records which lets us say "these are all the records that were broken" - e.g. "longest game in August", "longest game on neutral ice", "longest game on neutral ice in August", "longest game in August when the moon was full" (If it was). How do we stop just getting a list of more and more obscure records?

Comment: I think it's okay as long as they are documented records on a major site - not just some random blog, but Sportsnet.ca is certainly reasonable, or nhl statistics, something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the records that were broken, will update the answer if I find out more:

- **Most saves in a playoff game** <sup>[1](https://www.sportsnet.ca/hockey/nhl/multiple-records-fall-lightnings-unforgettable-ot-win-vs-blue-jackets/)</sup> :
  85 by [Joonas Korpisalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joonas_Korpisalo) of CBJ (since shots started being tracked in 55-56 season)

  - Note: Some resources award the most saves in a playoff game to [Normie Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normie_Smith), with [90](https://twitter.com/PR_NHL/status/1293357378541367296) or [92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NHL_records_(individual)#Goaltending) saves, who played in net for the Detroit Red Wings in the longest NHL game ever against the Montreal Maroons in 1936. However, this was before shots (and incidentally saves) were officially tracked by the NHL. So Korpisalo holds the *official* mark of the most saves in a playoff game.
- **Total combined shots** <sup>[1](https://www.sportsnet.ca/hockey/nhl/multiple-records-fall-lightnings-unforgettable-ot-win-vs-blue-jackets/)</sup> :
  151 combined by both teams. CBJ had 63, TBL had 88
- **Most shots by a team in a game** <sup>[1](https://www.sportsnet.ca/hockey/nhl/multiple-records-fall-lightnings-unforgettable-ot-win-vs-blue-jackets/)</sup> :
  88 by TBL (since shots started being tracked in 55-56 season)
- **Most shots by a team in all OT periods of a game** <sup>[2](https://records.nhl.com/records/playoff-team-records/shots-on-goal/most-shots-one-team-ot-playoffs)</sup>:
  47 by TBL (stats being kept since 65-66 season)
- **Most time on ice** <sup>[1](https://www.sportsnet.ca/hockey/nhl/multiple-records-fall-lightnings-unforgettable-ot-win-vs-blue-jackets/)</sup> :
  65:06 by [Seth Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seth_Jones_(ice_hockey)) (since ToI has been tracked in 97-98 season)

Also specifically checked for the following, which the game didn't produce a record for:

- Blocked shots by team and a player
- Faceoffs by team and a player
- Hits in a game by player
- Penalties by a team

Comment: That's why I have "(since shots started being tracked in 55-56 season)" on the saves, but sure, I'll make an explicit note about it too

Comment: Added explicit note

Comment: Thanks - it certainly qualifies as the record, just thought it was worth adding the note for curious passersby. :)